# NestJS project starting when i running migration generate

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

When i running `npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n CreateUserTable` migration successfully generates, but  at the same time my project is starting. When i running `migration:create` all works fine and project doesn't starts.
I tried

1. change `ts-node` to `node`.
2. run `npx typeorm` instead of `npm run typeorm`
3. changing `dist` folder to `src`
4. create `mig:gen` scripts

Here's error log

```
> ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli "migration:generate" "-n" "CreateUserTable"

[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:24     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:24   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it
 now has an active connection session.
    at AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (C:\Users\whitered932\Projects\wr-todo\src\error\TypeORMError.ts:7
:9)
    at new AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError (C:\Users\whitered932\Projects\wr-todo\src\error\AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError.ts:8:9)    
    at ConnectionManager.create (C:\Users\whitered932\Projects\wr-todo\src\connection\ConnectionManager.ts:57:23)
    at C:\Users\whitered932\Projects\wr-todo\src\globals.ts:77:35
    at step (C:\Users\whitered932\Projects\wr-todo\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\whitered932\Projects\wr-todo\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:124:57)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\whitered932\Projects\wr-todo\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:24     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +7ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:24     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +2ms
Migration C:\Users\whitered932\Projects\wr-todo/src/migrations/1643293402567-CreateUserTable.ts has been generated successfully.
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:27     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +3152ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:27     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:27     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:27     LOG [InstanceLoader] UserModule dependencies initialized +3ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:27     LOG [InstanceLoader] TaskModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:28     LOG [RoutesResolver] TaskController {/task}: +344ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:28     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/task, GET} route +5ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:28     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/task/:id, GET} route +3ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:28     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/task, POST} route +2ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:28     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/task/:id, PATCH} route +3ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:28     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/task/:id, DELETE} route +3ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:28     LOG [RoutesResolver] UserController {/user}: +3ms
[Nest] 6648  - 2022-01-27 19:23:28     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +7ms
Завершить выполнение пакетного файла [Y(да)/N(нет)]? Y
```

Here's my files
package.json scripts

```json
 "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  },
```

ormconfig.json

```json
{
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "postgres",
    "entities": ["dist/**/*.js"],
    "migrations": ["dist/migrations/*.js"],
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "src/migrations"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `keepConnectionAlive` in your `ormconfig.json` file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).